# What is the appropriate directory to store scripts and their output?

Tags: linux, shell, naming-conventions, fhs

What is the most appropriate folder to store both scripts and their output (some txt files) on linux os? The scripts and their directory need to have 755 permission.

Is there an appropriate directory, that already exists, for that purpose or where should I create one?

Comment: Often, users store scripts in their personal `~/bin` directory. I wouldn't store their output there though. Create some other directory of your choosing for output, e.g. `~/output`.

Comment: /usr/local is another option. This way you can put your scripts in /usr/local/appname/bin and your output in /usr/local/appname/log

Answer (score 0):

The typical directory for the scripts is `~/bin`, which needs to be created. Do not mix scripts and output! The output files should be stored separately, in directories named according to the naming convention that suits your work best. Often, these directories are named per project, and there is more than one such directory. The directories can be named, for example, `~/prj_name/in` and `~/prj_name/out` for input and output, respectively. But there is no convention for those.

Answer (score 0):

`$HOME/.local/share` is the right place for data according to the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html):

> `$XDG_DATA_HOME` defines the base directory relative to which user specific data files should be stored. If `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is either not set or empty, a default equal to `$HOME/.local/share` should be used.

I've also seen `~/.local/bin` used for binaries by [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).  I'm not sure if this is defined in a spec anywhere.